# How to execute process memory?

Tags: c, api

I want to inject my code into some process and, I want to execute my injected code.

I can inject a code  like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define t_process_name example
BYTE code[7] = { 0x6A, 0x00 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
/*
   0:push 0
   2:jmp 521595
*/
int main(){

HWND hWnd = NULL;
DWORD pid = NULL;
HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
BYTE* space = NULL;
BYTE* dst = 0x521595;
int i = 0;
hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, t_process_name);
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);
space = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(code), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
code[2] = 0xe9;
*(DWORD*)(code + 3) = (DWORD)(dst - (space+2)) - 5;

WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, space, code, sizeof(code), NULL);

// and...   
}
```

But I don't know how to execute my injected code.  (push 00 , jmp 521595 )
Are there any API or Way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you want to patch try diablo2oo2's Universal Patcher (windows only). It can create loader/patcher for your application. You're better off editing the source code directly.

edit: obviously this doesn't inject to other processes but if i may ask why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact assembly that needs to be executed you can do that with the `asm`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C